# Access element attributes in `ref` callback

Tags: javascript, solid-js

I have this component:

```
function Div() {
    return (
        <div id="hello" ref={el => {
            console.log(el.id) // <empty string>
        }}/>
    )
}
```

I'd like to access the element's attributes in the `ref` callback, but they all seem to have default values. I know I can do something hacky like this:

```
function Div() {
    return (
        <div id="hello" ref={el => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(el.id) // "hello"
            })
        }}/>
    )
}
```

Any downsides to this? Is there a better way or is this the canonical way? Couldn't find this behavior in the [docs](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#ref).

Comment: Why not use `onMount` to read after getting connected to the `DOM`? The call back function gets called before being connected to `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

The element is not inserted into the page yet when the `ref` function is invoked, that is why any layout related values like `width`, `height`, `position` are 0.

If you need those values, you need to access them via an `onMount` hook which is guaranteed to run after the element is inserted into to the DOM.

```js
const App = () => {
  let el: HTMLDivElement;
  
  onMount(() => {
    console.log(el);
  });

  return <div ref={el!}>Some element</div>
}
```

The non-null assertion is needed to suppress the type error which should not be a problem because we know for sure the element will be available in that callback function.